# Linq Join.Where vs Where.Join performance diff

Tags: linq

Is there any difference in performance for linq in following case:

```
db.Table1.Where(p=>p.Item == 2).Join(db.Table2).Where(pq => q.Item == 3).Join(db.Table3).Where(pqr.r.Item == 3)
```

vs

```
db.Table1.Join(db.Table2).Join(db.Table3).Where(pqr => pq.p.Item == 2 && pqr => pq.q.Item == 3 && pqr.r.Item == 3)
```

Comment: Have you tested and looked for a performance difference?

Comment: This should really be on Code Review rather then Stack as it says in the [code review tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) "Ask about... The quality of your working code with regards to: Best practices.. Performance"

Comment: @hjardine What makes you think that the poster is seeking open-ended critique? This is a fine question for Stack Overflow, as it is seeking understanding of two code excerpts.

Comment: @200_success it is clearly about performance of two working pieces of code, i'm not going to flag, but he would get a better response on Code Review as that is what it was made for. Plus he is asking us to Review his Code, he doesn't ask what is the difference between.., only asks for the difference in performance so better suited to code review

Comment: @hjardine A question like this, with generic identifiers like `Table1` and `Item`, would get closed as hypothetical code.